# ProxyCommand with sudo

Tags: ssh, openssh

I'm trying to set up SSH so that I can easily log into an server that is accessible only via a sudo to an intermediate server.

From the command line, logging into it is of the form:

`sudo -u admin ssh destination.server.com`

This works without problems -- fair enough.  However, the following variants do not work in a ProxyCommand:

`ProxyCommand sudo -u admin ssh destination.server.com`

**Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.**

`ProxyCommand sudo -u admin ssh -t -t destination.server.com`

**tcgetattr: Invalid argument**

This last variant appears to actually exchange information with the destination server, but then it hangs:

```
OpenSSH_4.3p2, OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/me/.ssh/config
debug1: Applying options for destination
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec sudo -u admin ssh -t -t destination.server.com
debug1: identity file ...
debug1: identity file ...
debug1: identity file ...
debug1: loaded 3 keys
tcgetattr: Invalid argument
debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: Last login: Fri Jan  4 22:48:26 2013 from intermediate.server.com
```

I have the feeling that there is something I'm missing in the sudo / ssh interaction inside a ProxyCommand, but haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: Won't something like `ProxyCommand ssh admin@destination.server.com`work? Why is `sudo` necessary?

Comment: admin is set up with a public/private key pair

Comment: Couldn't you just encrypt the private key? The passphrase would serve the same purpose as the sudo password.

Answer (score -1):

If you want ease of typing:

```
alias dest_on_server='sudo -u admin ssh destination.server.com'
```

then *dest_on_server* gets you there.  Of course, replace *dest_on_server* with whatever short name you want.

The next alternative is ssh in the long way and add your own public key in the **`$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys`** file.  Make note of the user id, then `ssh user_id@destination.server.com`.

Comment: not at all comprable with an ssh config with a proxycommand.